# CodeSmells for python using Pyscent error

Tags: python

I am getting this error while executing the Pyscent codesmell. I have all the dependencies installed.

Thanks for your help.

```
C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master>python pyscent.py "C:\Users\abhil\Desktop\tst"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\pyscent.py", line 46, in <module>
    detector.detect_main("./code-dump/" + os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]))
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\detector.py", line 34, in detect_main
    detect_pylint_output(directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\pylint_output_detector.py", line 9, in detect_pylint_output
    output_list = detect_pylint_output_helper(directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\pylint_output_detector.py", line 37, in detect_pylint_output_helper
    output = output_long_methods(directory).decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\CodeSmellHandlers\HandleLongMethodSmell\long_method.py", line 19, in output_long_methods
    result = run(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE , cwd=directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master>python pyscent.py "C:\Users\abhil\Desktop\tst\tst.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\pyscent.py", line 46, in <module>
    detector.detect_main("./code-dump/" + os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]))
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\detector.py", line 34, in detect_main
    detect_pylint_output(directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\pylint_output_detector.py", line 9, in detect_pylint_output
    output_list = detect_pylint_output_helper(directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\pylint_output_detector.py", line 37, in detect_pylint_output_helper
    output = output_long_methods(directory).decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\abhil\Downloads\Pyscent-master\Pyscent-master\src\Detector\CodeSmellHandlers\HandleLongMethodSmell\long_method.py", line 19, in output_long_methods
    result = run(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE , cwd=directory)
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\abhil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Tried with both folder path as well as a single file's path.
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code you try to run?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.